# Don't know how to create a class correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a class from an Entry widget. The thing is that I want to add a frame to it, and it should be a parent for the entry. That is like to create an entry that will not be the main in its class, which is weird. So I just have no idea how to do that. If I inherits from a frame, I will have a functionality of a frame, not Entry. If I did from Entry, I have no idea of how to put A frame to be the main. There is a simple try, which is not working:

```
class AdvancedEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(parent, width=300, height=50, background="black")
        self.main_frame.pack()
        super().__init__(master=self.main_frame, *args, **kwargs)
```

But then if I will pack this Entry, it will only pack it itself, but it should actually pack a frame. That is not working for obvious reasons, but I just don't know how to do that.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achive without classes:

```
main_frame = tk.Frame(width=300, height=30, background="black")
main_frame.pack_propagate(False)
main_frame.pack()
entry = tk.Entry(main_frame)
entry.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: You would need to add a `.pack()` method (and probably also `.grid` and `.place`) that does `self.main_frame.pack()`, rather than `super().pack()`.  Do the same for any other standard widget methods that should apply to the Frame rather than the Entry.

Comment: Oh, I see. Didn't expect that this will be such complex, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

There's different approach of what you're trying to do, it depends on what you prefer, you can try the different codes i give to see what's the best for you. All the given codes do the same thing : create your entry in a frame and a button to print the entry value.
First you can inherit your class from a frame (i know you didn't want it but i still show you that it's good):

```
import tkinter as tk

class AdvancedFrameEntry(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master=parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = self.var)
        self.entry.pack()
        
root = tk.Tk()

frame_entry = AdvancedFrameEntry(parent=root)
frame_entry.pack()

#Button to print the value of the entry
def print_entry():
    print(frame_entry.var.get()) 
button = tk.Button(root, text = "Print entry value", command = lambda: print_entry())
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Then you can inherit your class from an entry but define the parent frame inside the class before the super()**init**:

```
import tkinter as tk

class AdvancedFrameEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        super().__init__(master=self.frame, textvariable = self.var, *args, **kwargs)
        
root = tk.Tk()

frame_entry = AdvancedFrameEntry(parent=root)
frame_entry.pack()

#Button to print the value of the entry
def print_entry():
    print(frame_entry.var.get()) 
button = tk.Button(root, text = "Print entry value", command = lambda: print_entry())
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Finally you can create a frame outside of the class before creating the entry:

```
import tkinter as tk

class AdvancedFrameEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        super().__init__(master=parent, textvariable = self.var, *args, **kwargs)
        
root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

frame_entry = AdvancedFrameEntry(parent=frame)
frame_entry.pack()

#Button to print the value of the entry
def print_entry():
    print(frame_entry.var.get()) 
button = tk.Button(root, text = "Print entry value", command = lambda: print_entry())
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```